# Need to extract particular content from one long line content using redshift sql

Tags: sql, json, amazon-redshift

Hi I am trying to extract one particular content from one long list of content using redshift sql like below:

Column name is output contains below values:

{"actionCompleteName":"SUCCESS","herdStepName":"2000Rule","ruleVersion":{"versionId":"01a2066d-cbc7-4faf-89bf-b693f5e6028a","ruleId":"c959efcb-4072-4608-a2f7-3312e1ff1933","ruleName":"GetRule","ruleMetadata":{"category":"ARC","subCategory":"FC","errorMessage":"Rule to extract values"}},"executionDetail":{"ruleOutput":"{"ruleAction": {"event_message": "SUCCESS"}, "package": {"pro_cat": [{"value": "2305600"}], "pro_subcat": [{"value": "2305610"}]}, "reason": {"ErrorStatus": "SUCCESS"}, "sab_data": {"sab_it_name": "New AKB7 Replaced Remote for TV", "sab_pro_t": "REMOTE_CONTROL", "sa_pr_cate": "", "sable_product_subcategory": "", }}

From the above, I want to extract below particular content:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| sab_it_name | New AKB7 Replaced Remote for TV |
| sab_pro_t | REMOTE_CONTROL |

I am trying to use the syntax in the query:

```
select 
json_extract_path_text(json_serialize(output), 'executionDetail','ruleOutput','sab_data', 'sab_it_name') as it_name
json_extract_path_text(json_serialize(output), 'executionDetail','ruleOutput','sab_data', 'sab_pro_t') as pro_t
from table
```

The output come out as null. I reference this syntax from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT.html

Could someone please help me to extract the expected result:
New AKB7 Replaced Remote for TV
REMOTE_CONTROL

Thanks,
Raja

Comment: Probably the issue is that the string you've provided isn't valid JSON (according to a number of the online JSON  validators available). Try parsing it to the function IS_VALID_JSON and see what happens

Comment: Hi @Nickw,

Thanks for providing me the insight of the format as it is not valid json format. But I do not have control to change this output column format. Within the given format, is there any other way to extract this particular content ?

Answer (score 0):

```json
{
  "actionCompleteName": "SUCCESS",
  "herdStepName": "2000Rule",
  "ruleVersion": {
    "versionId": "01a2066d-cbc7-4faf-89bf-b693f5e6028a",
    "ruleId": "c959efcb-4072-4608-a2f7-3312e1ff1933",
    "ruleName": "GetRule",
    "ruleMetadata": {
      "category": "ARC",
      "subCategory": "FC",
      "errorMessage": "Rule to extract values"
    }
  },
  "executionDetail": {
    "ruleOutput": {
      "ruleAction": {
        "event_message": "SUCCESS"
      },
      "package": {
        "pro_cat": [
          {
            "value": "2305600"
          }
        ],
        "pro_subcat": [
          {
            "value": "2305610"
          }
        ]
      },
      "reason": {
        "ErrorStatus": "SUCCESS"
      },
      "sab_data": {
        "sab_it_name": "New AKB7 Replaced Remote for TV",
        "sab_pro_t": "REMOTE_CONTROL",
        "sa_pr_cate": "",
        "sable_product_subcategory": ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The JSON string that you are trying to parse with the function is not valid JSON hence you are getting no output.

I have tried to correct the JSON, could you try with this and see if you still have issues.

Comment: Hi@DataWrangler,

Thanks for providing me the insight of the format as it is not valid json format. But I do not have control to change this output column format. Within the given format, is there any other way to extract this particular content ?

Comment: Two possible options I can think of 1) Try and fix the string using SQL to make it valid json and then your existing code should work 2) use a combination of INSTR, LEN, etc functions to extract the information you want from the string

Comment: Thanks @NickW for your suggestion. I am able to get output by using this syntax as:

json_extract_path_text(replace(json_extract_path_text(json_serialize(output), 'executionDetail','ruleOutput'),'\\',''), 'sab_data', 'sab_it_name') as sab_it_name,

What I did is, I replaced the '\' to make format as valid json format, then I use regular json syntax to extract expected output.